Hammer Horror movie about a haunted door?
I think this one was released in Hammer's heyday - mid to late 1970s? I saw it on TV in the early 80s.
It was an anthology as I recall, centred around an antique door. Christopher Lee ran an antiques shop, and in each story (4 in total?), someone would come in, buy the door, install it in their house and suffer the supernatural consequences. At the end of the tale somebody would inherit the house from the now-deceased occupants and sell it back to this same antiques shop.
It was in colour, and the following will come as no surprise to anyone who knows anything about Hammer Horror:

English language
Made in England
Starred Christopher Lee and (I think) Peter Cushing

I've not had much luck with Google, or with looking through existing questions in here, and the prospect of trawling through Sir Christopher's filmography on IMDB is a bit daunting!

I'd like to argue the case about this being a duplicate. Two questions with the same answer doesn't necessarily make them the same question. My description and Baard Kopperud's are very different, having an approximate year of release and a setting in common but nothing else. Having read his question I wouldn't have known he was thinking of the same film, and even having read your answer I wouldn't have been certain (since I only remembered a small part of it myself)!

TBH the rules for ID are, as always, a bit different. Mods have shown tolerance for duping ID if the A's are the same and the Q's have some similarities (which they do here: they're both about an old horror anthology movie with an antique store dealer). But if this displeases you, I don't mind unduping it. (Mods?)

I'm not too worried. Having read your reply and the help page I see what you're saying. As long as people can still find the answer whether they remember the details that I do, or the details that Baard did - and judging by the bit in the help page that says "Some duplicate questions may eventually be deleted, but often they are left as a signpost pointing people towards the canonical answer to that question" I think that should be the case :)

I'm sick of Mods who mark a question duplicate because the answer is the same, even when the question is completely different. 'Some similarities' my butt.

Sounds like From Beyond the Grave from 1974 with Peter Cushing as the store owner.

Anthology film from Amicus adapted from four short stories by R. Chetwynd-Hayes strung together about an antique dealer who owns a shop called Temptations Ltd. and the fate that befalls his customers who try to cheat him. Stories include "The Gate Crasher" with David Warner who frees an evil entity from an antique mirror, "An Act of Kindness" featuring Donald Pleasence, "The Elemental", and "The Door".

The last story revolves around an ornate door purchased from the store. Here's the trailer:




Yep I think that's the one! I guess my recollection of it was even flimsier than I thought. Love that you figured it out even so :) - BTW apparently I "can accept an answer in 5 minutes", so I will. Thanks!

@DougMcLean No problem. :) (It also turns out to be a duplicate, though I didn't remember that at all.)
